# Multiple Modelview for Blazor Server Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor Page with one View, but I want to use two ViewModels for that, depends on which URL I use.

```
@page "/canSimStatic"
@page "/CanSimDynamic"
@using System.Diagnostics;
@using edge_cantraficSimulator.Data
@using edge_cantraficSimulator.ViewModels
@using System.Threading;
@using System.IO;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager


@if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("canSimStatic"))
{
    @inject ViewModels.CanSimStaicViewModell viewmodel
}
@if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("CanSimDynamic"))
{
    @inject ViewModels.CanSimDynamicViewModdels viewmodel
}
```

My problem is, no matter which of these both URLs I use, it always choses the second one as `viewmodel`

Comment: First of why are you injecting viewmodel you don't need to.  Second create one Viewmodel that has the 2 inside it and use the one you want.

Comment: If I dont inject it i cant use i in my razor page

Comment: `<h1>@viewmodell.SiteTitle</h1>`

Comment: Your model should actually be initialised in Get() method and should just be a property of the class.

Comment: Don't try and cater for two different scenarios in one "page", just have two pages - each injects the correct model and handles it appropriately - any truly shared code/markup can be extracted to child component(s) and re-used that way

Comment: You can't use code like that in *any* DI container. DI containers work either through constructor arguments or dependency properties. That `@inject` directive works the same as a `[Inject] ViewModels.CanSimStaicViewModell viewmodell {get;set;}` property. You can't use an `if` around `@inject` any more you can around a property.

Comment: If you really want to change the *component* at runtime, you can use [dynamic components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0) based on the component type `<DynamicComponent Type="@componentType" Parameters="@parameters" />`. Keep in mind that Blazor isn't MVC, it's essentially React# and deals with *components*, not viewmodels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@inject` is Razor code and is like a directive.  You can't use it in logic loops like you have done.

You need to load both and then select which one you want to use.  You can do something like this:

```
@code
{
[Inject] private ViewModels.CanSimStaicViewModell viewModelStatic {get; set;}
[Inject] private ViewModels.CanSimDynamicViewModdels viewModelDynamic {get; set;}

private object viewModel;

protected override void OnInitialized() {
   if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("Dynamic"))
      viewModal = viewModelDynamic;
   else
      viewModal = viewModelStatic;
}
```

Whether you use object or say `ICanSimViewModell` depends on how you're using it.  I would suggest defining an interface that both "models" conform to and then

```
private object viewModel;
```

becomes:

```
private ICanSimViewModell viewModel;
```

Comment: I've not seen an inject used like a property before! the normal syntax is a private field, e.g. `@inject SomeMode mymodel;`

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious about that, too.  In code, I'm used to injecting in a constructor and in markup using @inject.  I've never seen the [Inject] directive in code before.  Is it new, or did I have a hole in my knowledge?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - it has been around for a while. I think that `@inject` is compiled to `[Inject]`

Comment: So it's just a cosmetic difference?  It doesn't affect the page life cycle at all?

Comment: They are exactly the same. From the hidden files:  `[global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.InjectAttribute] private WeatherForecastService ForecastService { get; set; }`

Comment: You learn so something new every day!  As @HenkHolterman says, `@inject` gets compiled as [Inject] - check your *obj* directory g.cs files.  It's how you inject when writing components as pure CS code classes.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this with output the URl to the page:

```
@if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("canSimStatic"))
{
   <p>First Option from @NavigationManager.Uri</p>
}
else if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("CanSimDynamic"))
{
    <p>Secound Option from @NavigationManager.Uri</p>
}
```

both show "Secound Option from .../CanSimDynamic". So Blazor seem to handel both internally  with the same Uri. So I would recommend to use a url parameter for this:

```
@page "/canSim/{Option}"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("Dynamic"))
{
    <p>First Option from Url  @NavigationManager.Uri - Option @Option</p>
}
else if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("Static"))
{
    <p>Secound Option from Url  @NavigationManager.Uri - Option @Option</p>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public String Option { get; set; }
    
    //...
}
```

you can use the url e.g. in NavMenu like:

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="canSim/Dynamic">
   <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
</NavLink>
```